# Please tell me about this XNA development problem on DELL inspiron !

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, xna

Hello friends i am using Dell Inspiron 1525
 with core 2 duo 2.0 GHz processor 4 GB RAM.

With this configuration can I develop XNA apps
on my laptop?

i am having Directx 11 but WDDM 1.0 ? how to update it to WDDM 1.1 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the new driver - like it says in this duplicate post:

[I am having Directx 11 but WDDM 1.0 ? how to update it to WDDM 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333099/i-am-having-directx-11-but-wddm-1-0-how-to-update-it-to-wddm-1-1)

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are as documented here.

[Setup and System Requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Note your display driver needs to be Directx10 minimum and WDDM1.1 compliant.

Comment: ya sure but is it necessary to have a dedicated graphic card on our system?

Comment: No, the requirement is on the display driver. Search for directx and WDDM in the text output from Start | DXdiag | Save All Information.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203925.aspx

> To execute and debug XNA Framework games for Windows Phone with the Windows Phone emulator, you need a graphics card that supports, at minimum, DirectX 10, with a supporting WDDM 1.1 driver.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron_1525):

> System specifications
>
> ...
>
> Graphics Processor: integrated Intel GMA X3100 graphics (Previously changed to 965 Express).

And again, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_X3100):

> Intel introduced Direct X 10 for the X3100 and X3500 GPUs in the Vista 15.9 drivers, though any release of DX10 drivers for the X3000 is uncertain. WDDM 1.1 is supported by X3100 but DXVA-HD is not.

So assuming you have the Intel GMA X3100, yes you can develop XNA apps on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I think, according to [the download page for Game Studio 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9ac86eca-206f-4274-97f2-ef6c8b1f478f), you need a graphics card capable of Shader Model 1.1 (preferably 2.0). If Dell's website listed your computer correctly, you have a [GMA x3100](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Graphics-Media-Accelerator-X3100.2176.0.html) which has DX10 and Shader Model 3.0.
The other specs are fine too. So off you go! :)

Comment: ok , i am not having a graphic card in my laptop so it means i cannot create apps using XNA framework. while i am having DirectX 11 installed .

Comment: @Abishek: Pretty sure you do have a graphics card... it's just an integrated graphics card.

Comment: following error encountered each time i try to run XNA project on emulator                The current display adapter does not meet the emulator requirements to run XNA Framework applications.