# I am having Directx 11 but WDDM 1.0 ? how to update it to WDDM 1.1?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, xna

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please tell me about this XNA development problem on DELL inspiron !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332709/please-tell-me-about-this-xna-development-problem-on-dell-inspiron)

Hi guys,

I  am having Directx 11 but WDDM 1.0 ? how to update it to WDDM 1.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to download a new display driver through windows update or from your display driver manufacturer.

If one is not available, you will need to change your display adapter hardware.